# how to build fast api python script on jenkins and fast api should run forever

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, fastapi, cicd

I have written a fast api. I want to build it CI/CD pipeline. I want to run fast api forever until I manually interrupt it.
I am very new to jenkins. I have written a Jenkins pipeline script which is followed.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git url: 'https://gitlab.com/something1234/test.git', branch: 'hello'
            }
        }
        stage('deploy'){
steps {
            sh """
            ls
            #!/bin/bash
            echo $PATH
            echo $HOME
            . /home/soleman/anaconda3/bin/activate tensor2
            conda activate tensor2
            python api.py
            
            
            """
        }
        }
    }
}
```

when I start build this script.The build runs forever instead of success beacuse of python api is running. As shown in figure.

[image]

How to build it successfully and deploy it? Please guide.

I don't want to use dockers as I am utilizing system own variables.

Comment: Replace the line `python api.py` with `nohup python api.py >> /tmp/server.log 2>&1 &` This will run your python api in background and you can track if it is running using the process id and also check the logs present in path `/tmp/server.log` (you can change the log path or omit it if not needed, if omitted you can check logs in nohup.out file)

Comment: Will it share live logs.

Comment: Yes it do share the live logs in path /tmp/server.log